# Getting current Activity name in service class

Tags: java, android, android-activity, service

Hello I'm trying to get the current Activity name (title of the activity) in a service class.

I have tried

```
ActivityManager am2 = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
listelement = am2.getRunningAppProcesses().get(0).processName;
```

but it's not working. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Try this

// get current top activity

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this .getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            List<RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
            ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
            String Actvity_Name = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getClassName();
            String PKG_Name = componentInfo.getPackageName();
```

> //Apply Check by this way

```
if(Actvity_Name.equals("com.example.Your_Activity"))
            {               

            }
```

> // add Permission in Manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_PACKAGE_SIZE"/>
```

Comment: How can I do this every 30 seconds? i put it on a timer but getSystemService doesnt want me to do it.

Comment: can you share your class code where you are using this?

Answer (score 0):

Services are not tied to activities, so there isn't a direct way to do it.

What I suggest: extend your activities from a BaseActivity.java where in `onResume()` you can save current activity name as a static variable in your application class. Then this will be available everywhere in your app.

```
public class App extends Application {
    public static String currentActivityName;
}

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        App.currentActivityName = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I access this variable on the service?

Comment: App.currentActivityName;

And make sure you know how to properly implement an Application class in Android.

Comment: this error accurs:  A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/databases/auto_complete_suggestions.db' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed 

even tho i'm only doing: listelement = App.currentActivityName;

Comment: I'm trying to track the activites which are clicked on. Even though I'm on Activity2 it says the name of Activity1 which can't be true.

Answer (score -1):

Knowing that `ActivityManager` manages Activity, so we can gain information from `ActivityManager`. We get the current foreground running Activity by

```
 ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 20)
    {
     String mPackageName = am.getRunningAppProcesses().get(0).processName;
    }
    else
    {
      String mpackageName = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();
    }
```

Comment: getRunningTasks is deprecated. and how do i save this in a String?

Comment: I dont want to know the package name but the activity name